# Correct jQuery to read from a select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

My script doesn't seem to be working correctly, what I'm trying to get is pretty self explanatory. I have tried several diffrent ways to make this work, searched around and tried to solve it.

I also tried to check the chrome log via `console.log()` but it didn't run the code through.

So **if** you know the solution to make it work I would appreciate the answer on how you solved it and what was wrong in the code.

**NEW:** The fiddle below includes the HTML.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#cart_review .quantity option :selected').change(function (event) {
        $quan = $(this);
        console.log($quan.parent().next()[0]);
        $quan.parent().next().find('.price').text(function () {
            return $quan.val() * parseInt($(this).attr('data-val'), 10) + ' kr';
        });
            var total = 0;
            $('#cart_review .price').each(function(k, v){
                total += parseFloat($(v).text(), 10); 
            });
            $('#total').text(total + ' kr')
    });

});
```

Check out this **[jfFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tweath/uQ2F8/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option does not have change event, select does. You need to Change the handler to:

```
 $('#cart_review .quantity').change(function (event) {
     //rest code
 });
```

**[jfFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQ2F8/1/)**

Comment: I tried that but that was after I realised I've been using the wrong ID the whole time.. Accepted. @Milind Anantwar

Comment: How do I calculate the shipping and the discount within the $total_price? @Milind Anantwar

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
 $('#cart_review .quantity').change(function (event) {
 // your logic here
}
```

instead of

```
$('#cart_review .quantity option').change(function (event) {}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uQ2F8/2/)

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/uQ2F8/3/

```
$(function(){
$('select.quantity').change(function (event) {
```

Hey I just changed your selector, I think this is what you're trying to accomplish. I did it with the first one.